# Renaming a computer against CSV from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

We're doing a mass rename of computers at a company and while I know there is a way to do this mass rename via Powershell from a DC, there are a lot of computers that are turned off and the script will need to be run again or stragglers will need to be individually fixed.

We have a remote monitoring/management system for this company that can deploy .bat files to computers as soon as they turn on, so I figured this way would be more thorough, and also has less chance of screwing things up seeing as it's a computer renaming itself as opposed to one script renaming everything.

I came across this, and it seemed like a really good idea, but for some reason the string for "%name%" can't be found in my semicolon delimited text file.

Here's what I think the script is / should be doing:

The script finds the name of the computer that it's being run on, sets it as %oldname% variable. Then it searches the semicolon delimited text file. This file contains current names and desired new names of computers. The two names are delimited by semicolon.

So the script tries to find the previously found name, then move over to the second part of the line to find the new name (tokens2 delims=;).

Then it loads that into the newname variable, that way the wmic command can run using oldname and newname.

However, the batch file cannot find the string.

---

```
for /f  %%i in ('hostname') do; set oldname=%%i

for /f "tokens=2 delims=;" %%i in ('type \\server\shared\test\names.txt ^| findstr /i "%name%"') do; set newname=%%i

wmic computername where name="%oldname%" call rename name="%newname%"
```

I get "Findstr: No search strings"   This tells me that it cannot properly find one of the names in the text file, and I'm a bit lost. I don't know if it has to do with syntax or how the txt file is set up.

The text file is laid out as such (using three fake lines to demonstrate formatting):

```
Test-L7;New-3284
Kitchen-7;New-1249
MikeS-7;New-3290
```

Comment: You are setting the variable oldname but then using name in your findstr.

Comment: Thank you. I used "%oldname%" and removed the space between the ^ and the pipe. It finally worked.